# Allow different parameters in action delegate

Tags: c#, .net, casting, delegates, action

I am trying to declare a action-delegate which allows set functions with different paremeter.

Here is my minimal example:
I have different void function like this:

```
private void Function1(string Parameter) { ... }
private void Function2(int Parameter) { ... }
```

I want to pass these functions in the same constructor. But this is not possible in this way.

```
Main
{
  AClass a = new AClass(Function1);
  AClass b = new AClass(Function2);
}
```

How do I need to define my Action (object is not working) - I don't want to overload my consturcor!

```
public class AClass
{
  public AClass(Action<???> Function) { ... }
}
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would either do this:

```
public class AClass<T>
{
    public AClass(Action<T> Function) { ... }
}
```

...or you would overload the constructor.

If you have something else in mind you need to provide more code to show us what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your class generic:

```
public class AClass<T>
{
    private Action<T> _action;

    public AClass(Action<T> function) 
    {
        _action = function;
    }

    public void Exec(T parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }
}
```

---

```
private void MyMethod(int param)
{
    // ....
}


var myClass = new AClass<int>(MyMethod);

myClass.Exec(10);
```

or

```
private void MyMethod(string param)
{
    // ....
}


var myClass = new AClass<string>(MyMethod);

myClass.Exec("Hello world!");
```